# kivy and python :calling a kivy application from another kivy application

Tags: python, kivy

I'm learning kivy at the moment and have tried to call the kivybird application from the app I'm building .what is the best way to access the kivybird app just by clicking a button and what parameters can I attach to the button?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about on Android opening another app?

Comment: No.Not on Android rather on PC but the kivy app running should open another kivy app on the same PC

Comment: That's more of a generic python problem, you can look up how you'd do it normally in python and just write a function that does that to bind to your button. Maybe the subprocess module will be what you need.